# Spring REST Docs - Avoid document the links

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, hateoas, spring-restdocs

I have this method in a SpringBoot 2 application:

```
@Test
public void shouldEchoTheParameter() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(get("/echo").param("echoMessage", "Test"))
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("Test")))
.andDo(document("echo-example",
preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
links(linkWithRel("self").ignored().optional()),
requestParameters(
parameterWithName("echoMessage").description("The message to be echoed")),
responseFields(
fieldWithPath("message").
description("The message echoed"))
));
}
```

I want to avoid to document this part of the payload:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/echo"
    }
  }
}
```

I included this:

```
links(linkWithRel("self").ignored().optional()),
```

but i have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LinkExtractor has been provided and one is not available for the content type application/vnd.pxs.echo.v1+json;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Do you want to document some links, just not the `self` link, or not document any links at all?

Comment: not document any links at all

Comment: You probably have to add a subsection called "links", and ignore that as well; because SpringDocs sees it as a regular field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`links(…)` creates a snippet that is specifically for documenting hypermedia links. As you don't want to document any links at all, you should avoid using the `links` snippet.

Instead, modify your use of `responseFields` to ignore the `_links` field and everything nested beneath it. REST Docs refers to this as a subsection and it can be documented using [`subsectionWithPath(String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/restdocs/payload/PayloadDocumentation.html#subsectionWithPath-java.lang.String-). You want to ignore the `_links` subsection so you'd do something like this:

```
responseFields(subsectionWithPath("_links").ignored(),     
    fieldWithPath("message").description("The message echoed"))
```